# passing variables into new page tab installations

Tags: facebook, get, parameter-passing, facebook-page, facebook-iframe

I would like to build a customized Facebook page tab for other page owners to instal onto their Facebook pages. Each page tab will need to have its own ID in the links that lead out of the page tab in order for us to track that page activity.

For example each page tab will have a list of products that link to the relevant product pages on an external website. Each of those links will have a unique ID parameter to we can track clicks and purchases. [e.g http://www.mydomain.com/products/product123.aspx?userid=12345]

So I need to create the userid variable in the link. Possibly using GET (or Request.QueryString for asp) to receive from the initial page tab installation.

From what i can see I might be able to use the app_data parameter to pass data over to the page, but when i tried it, it didn't work.

This is what i am using to install the page tabs 
    [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_data=12345]

I thought that this will pass the userid over to the new page tab, but it doesnt seem to work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction i would be very grateful.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what i can see I might be able to use the app_data parameter to pass data over to the page, but when i tried it, it didn't work.
>
> This is what i am using to install the page tabs [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_data=12345]

But you are aware, that appending &app_data=12345 does *not* mean you will get a GET parameter by the name 'app_data', right …?

The app_data will be passed as a property inside the signed_request parameter – so you’ll have to decode that one, and inside you’ll find your app_data value.

Comment: Hi @CBroe,
Thanks for that response, I have just been looking around and realized that. I am going to give that a try thanks.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, I am trying to find the easiest way to do this in C# for asp.net. Do you happen to know any links that point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am also trying to get this working but can't get the app_data to display ...how did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Why does 'each page tab' need to have an ID? 
The Page ID should be enough for you to determine which content to show (and it's passed to your app on each page load via the `signed_request`, and the page ID is also passed back to your app in the callback to the pagetab dialog

You could also request `manage_pages` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user to determine the list of pages they administer and if your app is installed on each

Comment: Hi Igy,
Thanks for responding to my question. 

Each page tab will need to have the page owners unique ID within all links on the page for our own internal tracking system to track clicks and purchases. We use an affiliate ID within the URL for us to be able to do this. [e.g http://www.mydomain.com/products/product123.aspx?userid=12345]

Therefore everyone who installs the page tab will have a different affiliate ID. Is this at all possible?